# Кривая иконка сайта "РУ"

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, design

В иконке сайта буква "У" шире, чем буква "Р" (5 пикселей и 4 пикселя, соответственно). Во всех нормальных шрифтах они одинаковой ширины.

Неправильно (сейчас):

[image]
[image]

Правильно (один из вариантов):

[image]
[image]

P.S. Это не единственный сайт со странными буквами. От рук дизайнеров также пострадали X, N и другие буквы.

Answer (score 5):

Думаю это следствие того что сайт имеет статус "бета". Все бета-сайты используют одинаковый дизайн. Иконки у них скорее всего сгенерированы автоматически (хотя есть и [три "особенных"](http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true) - Aviation, CiviCMS, Craft CMS).

Когда сайт заработает в нормальном режиме ему сделают собственный дизайн, красивую иконку и прочее и прочее. Например вот так выглядит полноценно работающий сайт: https://english.stackexchange.com/

---

По поводу автоматической генерации иконок - нет, это не требует больших затрат. Время, затраченное программистом на автоматизацию их создания приблизительно равно времени, потраченному дизайнером на их отрисовку. Тем более что их еще нужно положить в правильные папочки, прописать нужные пути к файлам и т.п. (А у каждого сайта как минимум 3 иконки - для "избранного", [увеличенная иконка](http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true) на странице со всеми сайтами сети (видна при нажатии на название сайта) и мелкая иконка в списке "горячих вопросов сети"). С автоматизацией все становится гораздо проще.

Кстати, похоже у Хрома и файрфокса используются разные иконки. Вот иконка в файрфоксе:

[image: Файрфокс]

А вот в хроме:

[image: Хром]

На этом увеличенном скриншоте "Актуальных вопросов сети" видно, что на шаблон в виде облачка накладывается текст, причем если текст слишком широкий (WW или PCG), он не влезает в границы облачка и иконка деформируется (синий фоновый прямоугольник выходит за границы облачка). Не похоже что это дело рук дизайнеров, скорее здесь работа "тупого" кода не рассчитаного на широкие буквы:

[image: Синяя плашка под текстом выходит за границы облачка]

Comment: Если бы иконки были сгенерированы автоматически, то существовал бы шрифт с такими буквами. А как я уже сказал, в нормальных шрифтах буквы не делают разной ширины только из-за того, что так проще рисовать. И автоматизируют то, что делается часто. Автоматическое создание иконок вряд ли окупится даже в масштабах SE.

Comment: Расширил ответ по поводу иконок.

Comment: Я поверю в автоматику, только если вы найдёте шрифт с точно такими буквами. Вы его не найдёте. :)

Comment: Судя по [этому посту](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226231) AnnaLear♦ должна быть в курсе технических деталей.